# Using same validation logic for Rest, JSF, biz layer

Tags: validation, jsf, jakarta-ee, jpa, jax-rs

I'm wondering if there is a way and if there is, what is the correct one, to use same validation logic (**one implementation**) for JSF, in EJB beans and web services - rest (RestEasy).

Currently Hibernate entities are used across all layers, because I feel my project is too small to complicate it with additional DTOs on the presentation layer, but the rest service will use DTOs.

How do I approach this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java EE offers JSR303 Bean Validation API for exactly this purpose. You perhaps already have seen them around, `@NotNull` and friends. This is by default automatically recognized and supported by both JSF and JPA. JAX-RS usually don't have a "view" which should take/validate input, so it's not of relevance here.

So, instead of e.g. JSF

```html
<h:inputText value="#{bean.entity.property}" required="true" />
```

with solely

```
private String property;
```

you can just use

```html
<h:inputText value="#{bean.entity.property}" />
```

with

```
@NotNull
private String property;
```

This can then also be used by JPA in case you're putting data via JAX-RS.

Only thing you need to take into account in JSF side is that it by default sets empty fields as empty string instead of `null`. You use the following `web.xml` context parameter to tell JSF to interpret empty string submitted values as `null`:

```xml
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.INTERPRET_EMPTY_STRING_SUBMITTED_VALUES_AS_NULL</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

#### See also:

- [Java EE 7 tutorial - using Bean Validation constraints](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/bean-validation001.htm)
- [Empty input value does not triggger @NotNull but it triggers @NotBlank](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8235990/empty-input-value-does-not-triggger-notnull-but-it-triggers-notblank/)

Comment: Hey, Balus! Thanks for the quick answer, I do use JSR303 and JSF validators where that is needed. I see problems where I have to do more complex and cross validation where some fields depend on others or even on more than one, so there can be valid/invalid combination of filled fields in a DTO. That's why I intend to check those fields in the rest service, before I fill the Hibernate entites and save to database.

Comment: Just use a custom bean validation constraint. You can even validate at class level.